# Weird subtraction issue with PHP 5.3.10

Tags: php, math

I have a very strange issue with PHP.

I run this very simple code:

```
include("db_credentials.php");
//
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$sel = mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
  //
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tokens");
  $res = mysql_num_rows($result);
  //
echo (50000-$res);
```

but the final subtraction result is NEVER right. I tried `echo gettype($res)` and `$res` is an integer (what else could it be?), but I have no idea of what could cause this. Is it a PHP bug? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you mean "the result is never right"?

Comment: What is the value of $res, what answer are you expecting to get? and what answer are you getting?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass $conn to mysql_query? mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tokens", $conn);

Comment: @Jon: that the result is never the expected result!

Comment: @Dale: Only necessary with multiple connections

Comment: @Dale: the second parameter is optional.

Comment: Battery could you please clarify your question rather than give me tips on something different please.

Comment: @gulyan: the value of $res is the right one: it correctly counts the number of rows. The only strange part is the subtraction.

Comment: @Dale: 50000-$res=result isn't the expected one. Is this clear? Say, 50000-34500=23000

Comment: What is the real value of $res in this case? And which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @Dale: PHP Version 5.3.10 / MySQL Client API version 5.1.56

Comment: Why don't you try to assign 50000-$res to a separate variable and use that. The echo function may not be interpreting the calculation as you intend it to. As pointed out by Dale, it would be good to know the expected result compared to the actual result so that we could see how far off the expected the actual is. this could then be used to evaluate what is going wrong with your code....

Comment: Battery, please echo $res and 5000-$res. As was initially asked.

Comment: @Philip: I did what you suggested many times, with same result. In general, the result is only a little different, say it is expected 34280 and I receive 34210.

Comment: @Battery, we need the **exact** values you're receiving. It may not mean much to you, but that doesn't mean it has no relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've run into this before but can't remember exactly where or how.

This isn't an answer per say, but rather a suggestion.

Try this code instead

```
include("db_credentials.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$sel = mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tokens");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$res = $row['count'];

echo (50000-$res);
```

Comment: Fantastic! I remember now I read something about this in phpmyadmin regarding innodb tables, I'm not sure if php's mysql_num_rows sufferes the same issue.. but apparently it does. Glad to have helped :)